# Formulario HTML y JS

Tags: javascript, html, formularios

Algun fallo en el codigo???

> Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

HTML

```
<form>

        <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" />


        <label for="edad">Edad </label>
        <input type="number" name="edad" id="edad" />

        <input type="button" name="name" id="enviar" value="Enviar" />


    </form>
```

JS

```
function camposLlenos() {
    var llenos;

    if ((document.getElementById("nombre").value!=="") && (document.getElementById("edad").value!=="")) {
        llenos = true;
    } else {
        llenos = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: En tu formulario no se ve en que momento ejecutas camposLlenos(), que es lo que quieres hacer exactamente ?

Comment: Revisando el condigo no tiene ningún error ya que realmente nunca haces uso de la función. no entiendo que es lo que realmente quieres hacer, te recomiendo que lo expliques mejor..

Comment: @CamiloVasquez quiero que al hacer click en un boton enviar, compruebe que los campos no estan vacios

Comment: @DiegoHenriquez  quiero que al hacer click en un boton enviar, compruebe que los campos no estan vacios

Comment: Para eso solo tienen que llamar la función de esta manera   onclick="camposLlenos()"

Comment: lo que comentaron anteriormente está bien, de todas formas verifica tu código y el cache del navegador, por lo general es eso lo que genera problemas vacia el cache o abre una ventana en modo incógnito, busca información para que cuando estes en modo consola no se cache tu archivo js

Answer (score 2):

Para restringir el envío de tu formulario podrías usar el evento `onsubmit` el cual se le aplica al mismo formulario, este evento disparará una función que va a retornar `true` si se cumple la condición (envía los datos) o `false` si no se cumple (mensaje visual al usuario).

A tu formulario le faltaban los atributos `method` que es el método por el cual se vana  enviar los datos y `action` que es la ruta del archivo **php** que va a procesar los datos enviados.

```js
function camposLlenos() {
    if ((document.getElementById("nombre").value!=="") && (document.getElementById("edad").value!=="")) {
      return true;
    } else {
      alert('Por favor llene todos los campos');
      return false;
    }

}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return camposLlenos()" action="#" method="post">
  <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
  <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" />

  <label for="edad">Edad </label>
  <input type="number" name="edad" id="edad" />

  <input type="submit" name="name" id="enviar" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```